# Do move constructors and move assignment operators make sense in classes that don't hold pointers as member variables and don't manage resources?

Tags: c++

In the articles and books I have read so far, there are only move operations done in classes that hold pointers. Those operations fundamentally work by swapping pointers and setting the old pointers to `nullptr`. But what happens when `std::move()` is called on a class without any pointers using the default assignment operator? Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(int x) : x(x) {}
    int x = 0;
    MyClass& operator=(MyClass&& other) = default;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass a{ 10 };
    MyClass b{ 20 };

    std::cout << a.x << '\n';
    a = std::move(b);
    std::cout << a.x << '\n';
}
```

Result is

```
10
20
```

It seems to have worked, but how? Did it do anything different from a normal assignment operator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An explicit move constructor or a move operator can be specified for any class, whether it has pointer members or not. It is true that move constructors and operators are usually used with classes that have pointers of some kind. But that's only because in these cases there's a way to effect a move that avoids the more expensive overhead of copying.

A default move operation for a trivial type is equivalent to a copy operation.

A default move operation for a class is equivalent to a move operation for each member of the class.

Therefore, in your example, the move operation is equivalent to a copy operation, and has no observable differences.

However it is certainly possible to need a move operator for a class that has no pointer members, for whatever reason. A classical example is `std::thread`, which has a move constructor and an assignment operator but not the equivalent copy constructor and copy assignment operator. The contents of `std::thread` are implementation defined, but typically consist of an opaque handle for an operating system-specific thread identifier. This handle cannot be "copied" in any meaningful way, but its ownership can be meaningful transferred to another `std::thread`, and that's why you have move operators there.

Your own classes may have similar semantical requirements, too, even if they don't have any pointers of any kind.

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense but I didn't understand what "move operation for each member of the class." means. What does it mean to move each member of a class?

Comment: Well, when your secret mission, should you choose to accept it, is to move an entire class, you implement this mission as follows: move the first member of the class; then move the second member of the class; then the third one, until all members are moved. Each member of the class then gets moved according to its own rules.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, the source of a move operation is left in a *valid but unspecified state*.

The default move-assignment for built-in types is a copy, this includes pointers. If you use a defaulted move-assignment operator on a class with a raw pointer you will end up with two pointers to the same object.

So, you should write your own non-defaulted move-assignment operator if your class contains raw pointers that manage resources. Otherwise it will not meet the expectation of leaving the source in a valid state, since it may end up leaving the source with a dangling pointer and so on.

(Note - usually it's a good design to have any resource-owning pointer wrapped in its own smart pointer or similar class that has the correct move and destruction behaviour already).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yeah my answer ended up in a different direction than I imagined when starting it..:)  If they do write their own move assignment operator, it would be acceptable practice to have it leave `b.x` as some other value .

Comment: As Howard Hinnant pointed out, *valid but unspecified state* is for most of the standard C++ library — in the name of utmost efficiency.  With a few notable exceptions which have additional guarantees, such as for `std::unique_ptr` and `std::vector`.  Also, member functions without preconditions are still legit to call on an object after a move.  Your own user defined types can have whatever post-condition guarantees you program them for.  (But for my own sanity, I tend to follow the *valid but unspecified state* pattern.)

Answer (score 2):

If all of your data actually lives inside the class, i.e. no dynamic allocation, then a move gives you no benefit.  In this case

```
MyClass& operator=(MyClass&& other) = default;
```

is going to be turned into

```
MyClass& operator=(MyClass&& other){ x = std::move(other.x); return *this; }
```

and a move for an `int` is the same as a copy, so your move assignment is copy assignment.

Moving really comes into the scene when your class points to it's data.  Being able to move those types of objects means you spend the cost of copying the pointer to the data, but you don't actually have to copy the data, since you break the source objects connection to it.  Instead of an O(N) operation, you know have an O(1) operation, at the cost of the source object not having access to the data anymore.